# US Census Bureau Shapefiles with district IDs

Tags: shapefile, polygon, united-states, census

I am loading senate district polygon shapefiles from https://www.census.gov/cgi-bin/geo/shapefiles/index.php?year=2019&layergroup=State+Legislative+Districts into my Leaflet map. Well, to be accurate, I am first converting these shapefiles to GeoJSON with mapshaper.org. Anyway, we would like to color individual districts based on statistics such as income level. However, the shapefiles do not contain district IDs.

Are the polygons in these shapefiles organized in a consistent sequence that can be mapped to district IDs?

If not, is there another way to know to which district each polygon corresponds?

Comment: what do district id's look like?

Comment: `NAMELSAD` attribute has values like `State Senate District 14`

Comment: You can get all the US district GeoJSON maps also here: https://github.com/unitedstates/districts

Answer (score 0):

Something might have happened to your data when converting to GeoJSON, because all the info you need is already in that dataset.

I would try using QGIS to not only explore the data, but using it to export to GeoJSON and exploring the result of that export as well.

[image]